# Flexbox wrapper around internally scrolling div not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I've got a flexbox container around a max-height div with overflow auto and content inside that div which is taller than the max-height (reproduced below).

In Chrome/Firefox/Safari the #wrapper div respects its max-height and scrolls the inner content. In Internet Explorer, #wrapper is the full height of the inner content.

```css
#flex {
    display: flex;
    max-height: 100px;
}

#wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
}

#content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any `overflow: auto` in your code.

Comment: sorry, i was using an explicit "scroll" here, but the behavior is the same with auto or scroll. (changed now to "auto")

Comment: I don't have IE to test, but on Firefox the behavior seems the same as you described, and seems the correct one. Why do you set `max-height: 100px` to `#flex` instead of `#wrapper`?

Comment: The behavior on Firefox seems to be the same as chrome to me: what's visible on screen is 100px of red, which is scrollable.

Comment: In my actual use case, there's a header above the content, and I want the total height not to exceed a certain value, but i want the header to remain fixed and the content to scroll.

Comment: If you have a header above the content, you probably want `#flex {flex-direction: column}`. And it will fix the problem on Firefox.